# Can't create table `db`.`WRITER` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Hello I have an issue when trying inserting multiple foreign keys to a table. I have searched a lot of hours and still I don't figure it out.. It pops this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRC1S.png). I don't know what else I can do about that. Also I tried to add constraint .. foreign key ... references command and it didn't work.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db;
CREATE DATABASE db;

USE db;



CREATE TABLE BOOKS(
    Bno int not null primary key auto_increment,
    Title text,
    PDate date,
    Cno int,
    Cname text
);


CREATE TABLE AUTHORS(
    Ano int not null primary key auto_increment,
    Asurname text,
    Aname text
);


CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES(
    Cno int not null primary key auto_increment,
    Cname text,
    No_Of_Books int
);

CREATE TABLE SUMMARY_LANG(
    Bno int not null primary key auto_increment,
    Language text,
    FOREIGN KEY (Bno) REFERENCES BOOKS(Bno)
);

CREATE TABLE WRITER(
   Bno int,
   Ano int,
   Asurname text,
   Aname text,
   FOREIGN KEY (Bno) REFERENCES BOOKS(Bno),
   FOREIGN KEY (Ano) REFERENCES AUTHORS(Ano),
   FOREIGN KEY (Asurname) REFERENCES AUTHORS(Asurname),
   FOREIGN KEY (Aname) REFERENCES AUTHORS(Aname)
);

INSERT INTO BOOKS(Title,PDate,Cname)
VALUES
('A first course in database systems','2014-01-01','DATABASE'),
('FUNDAMENTAL CONCEPTS OF PROGRAMMING SYSTEMS','1976-01-01','PROGRAMMING');

ALTER TABLE AUTHORS auto_increment = 100;
INSERT INTO AUTHORS(Asurname,Aname)
VALUES
('ULLMAN','JEFF'),
('WIDOM','JENNIFER');

ALTER TABLE CATEGORIES auto_increment = 10;
INSERT INTO CATEGORIES(Cname, No_Of_Books)
VALUES
('DATABASE',1),
('PROGRAMMING',1);

INSERT INTO SUMMARY_LANG(Language)
VALUES
('ENG'),
('GRE'),
('ENG'),
('FRA');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error)

Comment: [MySql, Is it a good practice to use 'text' datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493589/724039)

Comment: Read all the answers at the duplicate link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of SUMMARY_LANG is wrong

```
CREATE TABLE SUMMARY_LANG(
    Bno int not null primary key auto_increment,
    Language text,
    FOREIGN KEY (Bno) REFERENCES BOOKS(Bno)  <-- remove this reference
);
```

Remove the foreign key, because this is a Table that is used only as reference number to another table also called a helper table, because the text would be redundant in the referenced table.

But i can't see any column that references language.

So add a column to BOOKS, where you add the reference to SUMMARY_LANG and when you add new rows  SUMMARY_LANG  you won't get any errors anymore.

So the new  tables can be like this

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKS (
    Bno INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Title TEXT,
    PDate DATE,
    Cno INT,
    Cname TEXT,
    SNno int,
    FOREIGN KEY (SNno)
        REFERENCES SUMMARY_LANG (SNno)
);
CREATE TABLE SUMMARY_LANG(
    SNno int not null primary key auto_increment,
    Language text
);
```

Comment: I edit my table and now I have this message `Can't create table `db`.`BOOKS` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")` . Did you mean to create a foreign key in your last sentence ?

`CREATE TABLE BOOKS(
    Bno int not null primary key auto_increment,
    Title text,
    PDate date,
    Cno int,
    Cname text,
    Language text,
    FOREIGN KEY(Language) REFERENCES SUMMARY_LANG(Language));` @nbk

Comment: i added the correct syntax

Comment: thanks for helping me but still i have the same issue.. i copy and paste your solution but it didn't work @nbk

Comment: it works just fine https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fdea13195740b1ad405eb3c572d0c84a

Comment: I tried it with datagrip it didn't work.. anyways thank you very much dude @nbk

Comment: check the dbfiddle and you need the correct sequence, If you get an error , show me your own fiddle and i will see what i can do

Comment: it's not from dbfiddle but from my datagrip but anyways maybe it's a bug from sql. Because I had a lot of issues with foreign keys and on other computers they were working fine. @nbk